# What type to return from a Service method on Fail

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I've debated at times what to exactly send back if I create a WCF service to clients consuming my web service.  Usually I return custom DTOs and in that DTO I have a property called Success (bool) and also a couple property strings for errors that can be checked if Success is false.

But the client has to know (tightly coupled) about that DTO type in order to make the method call because it returns a DTO of x type.

I know I do want to return an object ...because I want to include the flag success and also always provide information if failed.  But then should I return some type of Interface?

I'm not quite sure what is best to returned if you want your service to be able to be consumed by ANY .net client application.

Comment: Why add a property to an object simply to confirm if a process succeeded? There is error handling built into the WCF Framework, MSDN Fault Handling in WCF Services...  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942778.aspx

Comment: Because I'm using that DTO for dual purpose.  If the property Success is true, that DTO represents a type that you can work with and will have data, otherwise if the success flag is false then you can also use that same type to check for errors as this DTO also has an Error property.

Comment: Ok so I assume that WCF services can't be consumed by non .NET clients then if you wanna use the Fault Handling?  I wanted to create a service that could be an endpoint to any .net app OR to any outside client such as Java...I guess that's not possible.  I just wanted to return a more generic type that could really be used by the world...but maybe WCF can only be used by .NET clients?

Comment: Arguably poor design mixing business and process logic into Domain Objects. Theres a lot of info online about returning exceptions for various WCF service formats, RESTFUL etc... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513227.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a server side error of a type which will require the caller to handle then you should wrap the error in a SOAP fault message.

This is the standard and intended way to pass error information back to your caller.

To pass a success/failure flag is kind of an anti-pattern, as you are forcing your consumers to interrogate the response object to know if there has been a failure.

In WCF, if you throw an exception in the service operation then WCF will automatically create the SOAP fault wrapper for you. This gives you an interoperable way to pass exception details back to your callers.

Answer (score 1):

If the client is also a .NET application, I'd probably just thrown an exception.

Comment: what if the client is not a .NET app?

Comment: And what if you wanna return custom errors, or error codes to the caller?

Comment: 1. if your client isn't .net, WCF shuold still wrap the exception on a SOAP fault message (as @hugh mentions). 2. If you need custom errors, just create your own Exception classes or populate the Data object of your exception.